# loop on insert in bulky from one table to another with bfile oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

- Table1

  - BF varchar2(255),
  - Name varchar2(100),
  - id Number
- Table2

  - BF BFile,
  - Name varchar2(100),
  - id Number

I am inserting over 20000 rows from Table1 into Table2. I get an error message inconsistency Datatypes, I want to maintain the BF as BFile.  How do I do it without inconsistency datatypes Error?

Below is my code.

```
declare 

  CURSOR c1
    IS
       SELECT name, id, address,  BF
        FROM table1 a

begin  
  for i in 1..20000 loop  
    for l_record in c1 loop
      insert into Table2 (name, id, address,  BF) 
      values (''' ||name||''', '|| id||', '''||   BF ||'); 
    end loop;      
  end loop;  
end;  
/
```

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

> You use the BFILE datatype to store large binary objects in operating
>   system files outside the database. Every BFILE variable stores a file
>   locator, which points to a large binary file on the server. The
>   locator includes a directory alias, which specifies a full path name.

You didn't say what's written in `table1.bf` column, so I suppose it is a name of that binary objects (such as a picture). If that's so, why do you need a loop and a cursor? A straightforward `INSERT` should do it. Besides, it seems that you got lost with all those escaped single quotes (I did).

Anyway: here's an example. I'm creating two tables as you mentioned. One of them contains a row, and subsequent `INSERT` inserts it to another table. `ROWNUM < 20000` is here to restrict inserts to 20000 rows. I presume there are more of them in your `table1` table.

First, connected as `SYS`, I'll create a directory (will need it later, during `insert into table2`):

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> create directory my_dir as 'c:\temp';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory my_dir to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Connect as `scott` and do stuff. Insert uses the [BFILENAME](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions012.htm) function which

> returns a BFILE locator that is associated with a physical LOB binary file on the server file system.

It accepts two parameters:

- directory (we created above)
- filename

---

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@xe
Connected.
SQL> create table table1 (bf varchar2(255), name varchar2(10), id number);

Table created.

SQL> create table table2 (bf bfile, name varchar2(100), id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into table1 values ('littlefoot.jpg', 'lf', 1);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into table2 (bf, name, id)
  2    select bfilename('EXT_DIR', bf), name, id from table1
  3    where rownum < 20000;

1 row created.

SQL> select * From table2;

BF                                                 NAME          ID
-------------------------------------------------- ---------- -----
bfilename('EXT_DIR', 'littlefoot.jpg')             lf             1

SQL>
```

Comment: It really worked, thank you so much. You answered my question.